# Slicing of images

Tags: image-processing

I have used the following command to slice a large image into blocks of 2x2 pixels:

```
convert -crop 2x2 +repage Logo.jpg sl%d.jpg
```

When I attempt to put the blocks next to each other in the order that they should be, I get a smaller size of the original image. I wonder if there is anything I should do to get the original size.

Comment: What software is this?

Comment: I am using Latex to read each image and put them in an array. An example is \includegraphics[scale=1]{sl0.jpg} to insert the first image in my array.

Comment: So, this is a $\LaTeX$ question?

Comment: I have experimented with different block sizes from 64x64 down to 1x1.  When I put these blocks in an array (matrix), the size of the resulting image decreases and decreases compared to the original image.  To be honest to you, I can scale the resulting image to make it larger.  However, finding the right scaling factor does not seem to be that easy.  The scaling factor I have used in the original image is 1, and the scaling factor I am using to include my blocks is also 1.